# I have a problem in bayesian networks get p(E|A)

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

I'm doing this book "Modeling and reasoning with Bayesian Networks" and I have this problem:

```
ConsidertheDAGinFigure4.14:
(a) List the Markovian assumptions asserted by the DAG.  
(b) Express Pr(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) in terms of network parameters. 
(c) Compute Pr(A = 0, B = 0) and Pr(E = 1 | A = 1). Justify your answers. 
(d) True or false? Why?
- dsep(A, BH, E) 
- dsep(G, D, E) 
- dsep(AB,F,GH)
```

I have done almost all the question, but I'm missing c) p(E=1|A=1), I have tried p(E and A)/p(A), but this does not seem correct and for p(A=0, B=0) is this correct p(A) p(B)=(0.8)(0.3), any help?? Thanks.
[image: Network]

[image: Parameters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering $P(E \vert A)$, you might first think about whether $E$ is dependent on $A$ at all. If this is not the case, it holds that $P(E \vert A) = P(E)$

And considering $P(A,B)$: Then $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$, if $A$ and $B$ are independent of each other.

If you understood how d-separation works, then you should be able to answer these questions yourself.

Comment: So p(A,B) is correct 0.8*0.3=0.24, and the second is no, there are no paths from A to E, well no open paths actually, but how do can I write it here, because is dependent on B then p(A=1)$\sum$p(B)p(E=1|B) or how

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso See my edit.

Comment: Ok, I got it since they are d-sep(A,{D,B},E), that means we can get it by simple independence, correct?

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso $\text{d-sep}(A,\emptyset,E)$ appears to be more important. After all $D,B$ are not given in the query.